# ./script.sh: line 8: /etc/passwd: Permission denied

Tags: bash, permission-denied, etcpasswd

I have this script which I can't execute:

```
#!/bin/bash

USERS="/etc/passwd"

for user in `$USERS | cut -f 1 -d ':'`
do
        echo $user
done
```

This is the output of `ls -l script.sh`:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user 94 Jul 30 21:24 script.sh
```

What am I doing wrong? :|
I also tried running it as `root` and with `sudo` and nothing worked...it's annoying...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to *execute* /etc/passwd and send the output to cut. You want to redirect the *contents* of the file:

```
for user in `cut -f 1 -d : < $USERS`
```